# Retrieving the hidden input value of an automatically generated parents child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to retrieve the input value of a child element from automatically generated elements in my document in order to use its values but i am having trouble accessing the child, How can i go about doing this? (im very new to JS)

```
var createCard = function (num, x) {
var div = document.createElement('div');
var classN = "card" + num;
var classX = "card" + x;
div.className += classX;
div.className += " card ";
div.className += classN;
div.style.opacity ="1"
div.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
   var div = $(e.target);
   var n = div.firstElementChild.value;   //here lies the suspected problem
   if (div.css('opacity') == "0.3") {
       div.css('opacity', "1");
       aNum(n);
   }
   else {
       div.css('opacity', "0.3");
       mNum(n);
   }
 });

var worth = document.createElement('input')
worth.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
worth.setAttribute('value', num);

div.appendChild(worth);
document.getElementById('gameArea').appendChild(div);
};
```

Comment: How are you calling `createCard ` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jquery to select an element's child.

There's multiple ways to go about this, [but I'd suggest checking out Jquery Selectors.](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp)

I believe the selector for a child of an element is .children(":first")

So you'd do

```
 var child = $("MyDivSelector").children(":first");
```

Comment: Yup Using     `var child = $("MyDivSelector").children(":first").val();` worked thank you very much :)

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

Set the id for the input

```
worth.setAttribute('id', 'hidworth');
```

Get the input

```
var hidWorth=document.getElementById('hidWorth');
```